# How to use an existing database with an Android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I have already created an SQLite database. I want to use this database file with my Android project. I want to bundle this database with my application.

Instead of creating a new database, how can the application gain access to this database and use it as its database?

Comment: -Use Lita tool for open database
-http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/58 -you can get installed/already use in app by eclipse DDMS perspective > explore > in list data>{your app package}>database>yourdb_file.db , explore window have import export option - here explore window you can import already create db push in mobile

Comment: I strongly recommend using `SQLiteAssetHelper`: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Answer (score 335, accepted):

**NOTE:**
Before trying this code, please find this line in the below code:

```
private static String DB_NAME ="YourDbName"; // Database name
```

DB_NAME here is the name of your database. It is assumed that you have a copy of the database in the assets folder, so for example, if your database name is ordersDB, then the value of DB_NAME will be ordersDB,

```
private static String DB_NAME ="ordersDB";
```

---

Keep the database in **assets folder** and then follow the below:

DataHelper class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window
    private static String DB_NAME ="YourDbName"; // Database name
    private static int DB_VERSION = 1; // Database version
    private final File DB_FILE;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        DB_FILE = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        // If the database does not exist, copy it from the assets.
        boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
        if(!mDataBaseExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try {
                // Copy the database from assests
                copyDataBase();
                Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
            } catch (IOException mIOException) {
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
            }
        }
    }

    // Check that the database file exists in databases folder
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        return DB_FILE.exists();
    }

    // Copy the database from assets
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_FILE);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    // Open the database, so we can query it
    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        // Log.v("DB_PATH", DB_FILE.getAbsolutePath());
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_FILE, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        // mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_FILE, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(mDataBase != null) {
            mDataBase.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

}
```

**Write a DataAdapter class like:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class TestAdapter {

    protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter";

    private final Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;

    public TestAdapter(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
    }

    public TestAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException {
        try {
            mDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException mIOException) {
            Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
            throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
        }
        return this;
    }

    public TestAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        try {
            mDbHelper.openDataBase();
            mDbHelper.close();
            mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "open >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

     public Cursor getTestData() {
         try {
             String sql ="SELECT * FROM myTable";
             Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
             if (mCur != null) {
                mCur.moveToNext();
             }
             return mCur;
         } catch (SQLException mSQLException) {
             Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
             throw mSQLException;
         }
     }
}
```

**Now you can use it like:**

```
TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(urContext);
mDbHelper.createDatabase();
mDbHelper.open();

Cursor testdata = mDbHelper.getTestData();

mDbHelper.close();
```

**EDIT: Thanks to JDx**

For [Android 4.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history#Android_4.1_Jelly_Bean_.28API_level_16.29) (Jelly Bean), change:

```
DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
```

to:

```
DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
```

in the DataHelper class, this code will work on Jelly Bean 4.2 multi-users.

**EDIT: Instead of using hardcoded path, we can use**

```
DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
```

which will give us the full path to the database file and works on all Android versions

Comment: This doesn't work on Jellybean 4.2 using multiple users. Is there any workaround?

Comment: OK, no problem. I figured it out anyway, If you change:

 DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";

to:

 DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";

in the DataHelper class this code will work on JB 4.2 multi users.

Comment: I have been trying to write to this database, I am new to android and have downloaded the new adt bundle. I have been searching the web for a resolution and have seen how JDx changed the DB path, I have also tried to change to this path but it wont work! Please has someone any recommendations so I can write to my database. thank you

Comment: @YaqubAhmad in my database file store in Assects folder in that lot of data is available my requirement is how to get that data and display in listview Any idea of this one....

Comment: @YaqubAhmad what is file size any limitations. what is maximum size of .sqlite

Comment: Some scenario:
_User opens application, then leaves the app by pressing home button. User go to Setting - Apps - <your_app> and then click the `Clear data` button_.
What will happen when the user comes back to your application? Shouldn't you override the method `getReadableDatabase()`?

Comment: What if I want to encrypt db file in assets folder before copying to sd card.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203987/android-database-encryption

Comment: I'm using this code but still can't resolved the FIRST run error of the application and still the "table not found". I used sqlite database. I've defined the database extension in the DB_NAME e.g : Example.sqlite and the File name on my databases folder under the assests folder is Example.sqlite .. Hope you would help me sir ;D

Comment: @YaqubAhmad does the edited code for jelly bean will work for the versions below it ?

Comment: You need to use the API number in the comparison, not 4.2, so >= 17.

Comment: it's good example, but it didn't work on some devices. some changes:  File dbFile = new File(myPath);
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbFile, null);
//        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

Comment: to JDx and others: There is a method `Context.getDatabasePath()` which is there to show you exact location of specific database (without the need for `DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";`   and other trash like this) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)

Comment: What about the situation when you use database in conjunction with ContentProvider (defined in manifest file). How to make the provider use custom database?

Comment: What should i do if in next release i have to add a new table or new column to a table ??? keeping the previous data save ....

Comment: The source code (sample project) link is out of date.

Comment: @Cjames Did you ever solve it? Or anyone else? I'm getting no such table errors no matter what I do.

Comment: @Cjames I had this problem. Something went wrong when copying the database from the assets folder the first time I ran this. Every subsequent run would try reading from the empty database and would fail when trying to select from a table.

If you uninstall, clean, and then run again it should re-copy the database. Check for any copying errors.

Comment: @Mike PM me your email address I'll send you a sample code

Comment: @Mumfi May PM me your email address. I'll send you a sample code

Comment: Database created (Y). I am new to this just wanna know what if I want to write something in this database? How can I do that?. Thanks

Comment: This ans is copied from http://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Comment: kindly make this change private static String DB_NAME ="YourDbName"; to private static String DB_NAME ="YourDbName.db";

Comment: The new database appears empty, but it is not, did anyone else have this problem?

Comment: DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/"; solved the issue for me on all huawei devices, thank you very much.

Comment: Does this code work in 2022, I want to try it in android 8.1. I am working with room database.

Comment: @JitendraKumar.Balla Which part? I've looked at the web archive and found no match.

Answer (score 23):

If you are having pre built data base than copy it in asset folder and create an new class as **DataBaseHelper** which implements **SQLiteOpenHelper** 
Than use following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelperClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
 //The Android's default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/package_name/databases/";
// Data Base Name.
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DBName.sqlite";
// Data Base Version.
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Table Names of Data Base.
static final String TABLE_Name = "tableName";

public Context context;
static SQLiteDatabase sqliteDataBase;

/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 * Parameters of super() are    1. Context
 *                              2. Data Base Name.
 *                              3. Cursor Factory.
 *                              4. Data Base Version.
 */
public DataBaseHelperClass(Context context) {       
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null ,DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
 * of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
    //check if the database exists
    boolean databaseExist = checkDataBase();

    if(databaseExist){
        // Do Nothing.
    }else{
        this.getWritableDatabase();         
        copyDataBase(); 
    }// end if else dbExist
} // end createDataBase().

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
public boolean checkDataBase(){
    File databaseFile = new File(DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME);
    return databaseFile.exists();        
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transferring byte stream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{ 
    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME); 
    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME; 
    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName); 
    //transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close(); 
}

/**
 * This method opens the data base connection.
 * First it create the path up till data base of the device.
 * Then create connection with data base.
 */
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{      
    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    sqliteDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);  
}

/**
 * This Method is used to close the data base connection.
 */
@Override
public synchronized void close() { 
    if(sqliteDataBase != null)
        sqliteDataBase.close(); 
    super.close(); 
}

/**
* Apply your methods and class to fetch data using raw or queries on data base using 
* following demo example code as:
*/
public String getUserNameFromDB(){
    String query = "select User_First_Name From "+TABLE_USER_DETAILS;
    Cursor cursor = sqliteDataBase.rawQuery(query, null);
    String userName = null;
    if(cursor.getCount()>0){
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    do{
                userName = cursor.getString(0);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    return userName;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // No need to write the create table query.
    // As we are using Pre built data base.
    // Which is ReadOnly.
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // No need to write the update table query.
    // As we are using Pre built data base.
    // Which is ReadOnly.
    // We should not update it as requirements of application.
}   
}
```

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 11):

I had trouble with the other DatabaseHelpers regarding this problem, not sure why.
This is what worked for me:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private static final String TAG = DatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();

  private final Context context;
  private final String assetPath;
  private final String dbPath;

  public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String dbName, String assetPath)
      throws IOException {
    super(context, dbName, null, 1);
    this.context = context;
    this.assetPath = assetPath;
    this.dbPath = "/data/data/"
        + context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/"
        + dbName;
    checkExists();
  }

  /**
   * Checks if the database asset needs to be copied and if so copies it to the
   * default location.
   * 
   * @throws IOException
   */
  private void checkExists() throws IOException {
    Log.i(TAG, "checkExists()");

    File dbFile = new File(dbPath);

    if (!dbFile.exists()) {

      Log.i(TAG, "creating database..");

      dbFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
      copyStream(context.getAssets().open(assetPath), new FileOutputStream(
          dbFile));

      Log.i(TAG, assetPath + " has been copied to " + dbFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }

  }

  private void copyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
    int c = 0;
    while (true) {
      c = is.read(buf);
      if (c == -1)
        break;
      os.write(buf, 0, c);
    }
    is.close();
    os.close();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you already have a database, keep it in your asset folder and copy it in your application. For more detail, see *[Android database basics](http://sspower3.blogspot.in/2011/09/android-database-basic.html)*.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using a [content provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html). Each data item used in the application remains private to the application. If an application want to share data accross applications, there is only technique to achieve this, using a content provider, which provides interface to access that private data.